# How to Implement inheritance in Jquery UI widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am trying to inherit a method from base widget to another widget.
here is my sample code

My base widget is

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("UI.baseWidget", {
        options: {
            testVal:''
        },
        _create: function () {
            alert(this.option.testVal);
        },

    });
});
```

and other widget calling this base widget is

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("UI.MyWidget", $.UI.baseWidget, {
        options: {
          testVal:''
        },
        _create: function () {
            $.UI.baseWidget.prototype._create.call(this);
        }

    });
});
```

and initilise the MyWidgetcode is'

```
$('#mydiv').MyWidget({testVal:'test widget'})
```

How can we pass testVal option from MyWidget to baseWidget call?
and I getting error some thing like

Uncaught TypeError: i is not a constructor

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).MyWidget is not a function

can please help me to fix this issue. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work OK: I only made one correction : changed option to options in `alert(this.option.testVal);` and the alert with 'test widget' popped up OK. You can also try to create the widget jquery `onReady` and see if that fixes the problem i.e. :

```
$(function () {
    $('#myDiv').MyWidget({testVal:'test widget'});
});
```

See my code at https://jsfiddle.net/5gmn6x7k/4/

Comment: HI @Dhananjay I already include the Jqury UI Library . Still the error is there " Uncaught TypeError: i is not a constructor"

Comment: @Arun Create a new fiddle or modify my fiddle code to replicate the problem if possible